# generate a valgrind gdb break from custom tool

Tags: gdb, valgrind

I've written a custom valgrind tool. With gdb attached (-vgdb=yes) I want to break gdb when discovering a certain runtime condition. Is there an example howto do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that

```
 VG_(gdbserver)( VG_(get_running_tid)() );
```

does the trick. It will enter remote target loop .

Answer (score 1):

The API available to tools is all described in the include files
located in the 'include' directory at the top of the valgrind
hierarchy. The include files are named pub_tool_xxxxxxxxx.h.

In your particular case, the file that gives access to the gdbserver
functionality is pub_tool_gdbserver.h, which a.o. describes
extern void VG_(gdbserver) (ThreadId tid);

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an example howto do this?

I am sure there is: after all, Valgrind does it itself when it finds a bug. So all you have to do is look how it does that.

Looks like [coregrind/m_gdbserver/m_gdbserver.c](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=valgrind.git;a=blob;f=coregrind/m_gdbserver/m_gdbserver.c;h=9913c882304be5f71308059af4d99aa5d78e758b;hb=HEAD) `call_gdbserver` and `helperc_CallDebugger` should be a good start.